# Regular expression for replacing using sed

Tags: regex, sed

What could be the sed syntax to replace the text from a yaml(qa.yaml) file which contain below line.

```
image: "1xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/abc-zyx-123/prod:a.b.c" 
image2: "1xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/abc-zyx-456/prod:1.2.3.4"
```

Now I what to replace the last version i.e "1.2.3" and "2.3.4" from the yaml file during docker build. I am taking parameter value from Jenkins. So lets say 1st parameter is **image** and second parameter is **image2**

I could have done but this a.b.c could be change so what the best reg expression for this scenario?

```
RUN sed -i -e "s@\a.b.c/$image" /qa.yaml
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: Do you want to change the version at the end of a line starting with some specific text? And if so, what do you want to change it to?

Comment: @Bohemian: I want to replace the version at the end with the value someone enter while build from Jenkins. I have added 2 parameters in Jenkins from there I am taking new values of the versions. Thanks for helping

Comment: I think you wish to change everything after the last `:` in the line? for ex: `echo '123/prod:a.b.c' | sed 's/[^:]*$/xyz/'`

Comment: @Sundeep: Everything after ':' but not ". Also I am taking values from jenkins so it is going to be ${xyz}?

Comment: yeah, I only gave an example, you can modify to suit your script for variables, etc.. regarding quotes, you can match it and add it back, ex: `echo '123/prod:a.b.c"' | sed 's/[^:]*$/xyz"/'` (you'd probably need to escape it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
sed -i "s@[^:][^:]*\$@$image" /qa.yaml
```

It will replace one or more characters other than a colon at the end of the string with the text in the `image` variable that should not contain `@` character. If it is there, replace `@` with `#`, or `~`, or `,`, just make sure there is no such character in the `image`.